# Java Concurrency more than one thead does not gets executed in threadpool

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, synchronized

I'm having a project where I have a client which makes calls to the webserver. The webserver continuously opens one connection to another server which serves a XML file. This XML file gets converted into Java objects. To perform these actions, I use a thread pool. 
First there is this worker thread with a while loop. In the loop I call another method to retrieve the XML data.

```
public static void startXmlRetrieval( String sbeSystem, String params ) throws Exception {
    Processable xmlEventTask = sTaskWorkQueue.poll();
    if ( xmlEventTask == null )
        xmlEventTask = new EventXMLTask( sInstance );
    else if ( !(xmlEventTask instanceof EventXMLTask) )
        xmlEventTask = new EventXMLTask( sInstance );
    ((EventXMLTask) xmlEventTask).setXmlRetrievalParams( params );
    ((EventXMLTask) xmlEventTask).setXmlRetrievalAddr( sbeSystem );
    sTaskWorkQueue.add( xmlEventTask );
    synchronized ( sLockObject ) {
        System.out.println( "Initiating thread to retrieve XML feed" );
        sThreadPool.execute( ((EventXMLTask) xmlEventTask).getTaskRunnable());
    // send the continuous thread from the ServerSessionHandler class to wait for this execution to finish
        sLockObject.wait();
    }
}
```

The above method executes and comes back to the object where the method is declared.

```
@Override
public void handleState( Processable task, int state ) throws Exception {
    switch ( state ) {
        case XML_RETRIEVAL_FAILED:
            recycleXMLTask( (EventXMLTask) task );
            //throw new Exception( "XML retrieval failed" );
        case XML_RETRIEVAL_COMPLETED:
            synchronized ( sLockObject ) {
                ConvertManager.startXMLConversion( sInstance, sXmlData );
            }
            break;
        case DATABASE_RETRIEVAL_FAILED:
        case DATABASE_RETRIEVAL_COMPLETED:
            recycleDatabaseTask( (DatabaseTask) task );
            break;
        case UNX_COMMAND_EXEC_FAILED:
        case UNX_COMMAND_EXEC_COMPLETED:
            recycleUnxCommandExecTask( (CommandOutputRetrievalTask) task );
            break;
        case ConvertManager.XML_CONVERSION_COMPLETED:
            synchronized ( sLockObject ) {
                removeXMLEventRetrieval( (TaskBase) task );
                sLockObject.notifyAll();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

In the cas section "XML_RETRIEVAL_COMPLETED" i want to pass another thread to the same threadpool to execute the conversion of the XML data. 
The problem is that the method ConvertManager.startXMLConversion is executed, but when it comes to a submit on the threadpool for submittng a callable (FutureTask), this call method is not executed anymore. 
For the Thread group in the debugger, it says "WAIT" and it's currently stuck in the Unsafe.park method which is called from the FutureTask.awaitDone method.

Please help me with what the thread is waiting for as I used the synchronized statement for the one thread wait for the other one, but the other one is only executed to a certain point and the stops. I also tried playing around with notify and notifyAll on the sLockObject without any success.

The ConvertManager.startXmlConversion method looks as follows:

```
public static List<XMLEventData> startXMLConversion( AbstractManager mng, Document xmlDocument ) throws Exception {

    sInstance.mCallingManager = mng;
    List<XMLEventData> retVal;
    Processable converterTask = sInstance.sTaskWorkQueue.poll();
    try {
        if ( converterTask == null )
            converterTask = new XMLToXMLEventConverterTask( sInstance );
        else if ( !(converterTask instanceof XMLToXMLEventConverterTask) )
            converterTask = new XMLToXMLEventConverterTask( sInstance );
        else if ( ((XMLToXMLEventConverterTask) converterTask).getTaskCallable() == null ) {
            converterTask = new XMLToXMLEventConverterTask( sInstance );
        }
        sTaskWorkQueue.add( converterTask );
        ((XMLToXMLEventConverterTask) converterTask).setXmlDocument( xmlDocument );
        System.out.println( "Starting new thread to convert XML data" );
        retVal = (List<XMLEventData>) sThreadPool.submit( ((XMLToXMLEventConverterTask) converterTask).getTaskRunnable() ).get();
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Exception( e );
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Right now, with your description (actually having the full class(es) would help a lot!), I would suppose you have a deadlock on your `sLockObject`since you create a lot of synchronized blocks with this object locking. (and you see your Thread in a WAIT status). Notify/NotifyAll are effective only when a thread is waiting, it won't help if you have a deadlock in your code

Comment: @asettouf There are in total three synchronized blocks. You say using this synchronized statement only once might would help to avoid the deadlock? I can upload the classes in use to my github, so you can have a glance on it. I much appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Please do upload your classes. What I am saying is that your code (as much as I see) might get you deadlock, I can't say anything for certain without additional informations. The thing is that if you use synchronize, I would imagine it is to avoid data races, so by removing synchronized blocks, you might this time encounter this issue, which in the end would not be a great solution. (again seeing the code would help clarify all these assumptions)

Comment: You can delete them, although I would suggest you to put a "cleaned" version so that others can help too...

Comment: @asettouf Is a good idea. I also wrote to you a gmail. I will delete it and upload a new version.

Comment: @asettouf Did you find any deadlocks in my code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138901/discussion-between-ralph-heerich-and-asettouf).